# Risk of outdated Drupal installations?

Tags: drupal

We've recently had several hacks on our one server. We've been advised to upgrade all scripts. The problem is, the Drupal installations. Upgrading these are a massive task. I would like to know, out of fellow Drupal users, in your experience, how unsafe is it to remain on a say version 6.10 as apposed to upgrading 6.28 (the latest)? Is there a point at which you can say:  this is really too old now and an upgrade is absolutely necessary?

I'm not too worried about the modules, my concern is the Core Drupal installation. Does it ever become a security risk, or can you stay on the older versions?

Comment: You need to upgrade immediately. See [this](http://drupal.org/node/3060/release?api_version%5B%5D=87) for a list of all the security vulnerabilities that have been fixed since Drupal 6.10. There are a _lot_. The point at which you say 'this is too old' is as soon as a security patch comes out that you don't have applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Upgrading these are a massive task"*

Not necessarily! I find using [git](http://git-scm.com/) a pretty safe way to deal with such upgrades.

My basic workflow is usually to: 
- create a [repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) with the current Drupal version.
- download the latest core version
- rsync the current version with the latest core version
- update the repository

As expected, I do all of the above on my local version, after checking that everything is working fine. I update the remote repository, then update the actual live site from git.

If you're not familiar with git, basic tutorials are easy to find online. The idea here is not to explain the process in details, rather to send you in the right direction. You will find that it's a pretty flexible workflow, a great way to update modules and generally any type of code.

Comment: Also if you use Drush is it really easy to update all modules rather than just core from the command line. Saves you a lot of time rather than downloading and unzipping all the updated modules.

Comment: @sovam Drush is clearly the easiest way to upgrade modules! I tend to prefer the method set above in order to upgrade Drupal core, still I would use Drush to download the latest core version :)